# SaleForce SDK Rich Push Notification with multiline message

Tags: marketing-cloud

[image]

I have integrated the Android Salesforce SDK into my project and tested the push notification.

But only a single line of text message is getting displayed when I attach an image to the push notification and the 2nd line gets truncated.
Whereas when no image is attached, the whole message gets displayed on 2 lines.
Is there any alternative way to show multiline text message in rich push notification beside customising the notification view.?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Android OS handles notifications with images and is not a byproduct of using the SDK.

Comment: hi @Bill Mote, I accept that this is how Android OS handles notification. Sale Force Sdk version 6.0.2 already handle most of the android notification style and we just need to pass the message. Hence, I just would like to know whether their latest sdk provide this feature(Rich Push Notification with multiline message) which can handle by using their properties or methods.

Comment: The SDK does not customize the Android views used to display notifications.